# minlength input field validation - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, validation

I have the JQuery validations below that just ensure that something is written within the input fields, I also have maxlength in the html.

However, I was hoping someone could shed some light on the situation and inform me on how I can add some type of minlength to the jquery code below so I don't require to do any additional functions?

```
 $('#form1').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).validate({
    rules: {
        txtusername: {
            required: true
        },
        txtfirstname: {
            required: true
        },
        txtemail: {
            required: true
        },
        txtpassword: {
            required: true
        },
        passwordconfirm: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        txtusername: {
            required: "Please enter your Username."
        },
        txtfirstname: {
            required: "Please enter your First Name."
        },
        txtemail: {
            required: "Please enter your Email."
        },
        txtpassword: {
            required: "Please enter your Password."
        },
        passwordconfirm: {
            required: "Please enter your password again."
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent().prev());
    },
    submitHandler: function (form, user) {

        CheckUser(form);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Example HTML -

```
<div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="txtusername" data-theme="d">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtusername" name="txtusername" maxlength="12"  placeholder="Enter Username"/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like below:

```
rules:{
    txtusername: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3
    },
}
```

Comment: I did try this early, but the reason it wasn't working was because I left out the comma after true :S. Thanks for your help buddy!